# Why is sys.stdin.encoding under PyDev / Jython different from standalone Jython console?

Tags: jython, pydev

I am trying to get [python-gnupg](http://packages.python.org/python-gnupg/) to work in Jython under PyDev under Eclipse. There is a problem which seems to be caused by the `sys.stdin.encoding`, which is tested  by python-gnupg at it's initialisation.

I found that the following script

```
import sys
print sys.stdin.encoding
```

outptus `cp850` when I run it from Python standalone in a console and from Jython standalone in a console. When I run it in Python under PyDev, it outputs `Cp1252`, and when I run it in Jython under PyDev, I get `None`.

Looking at python-gnupg, both encodings `cp850` and `Cp1252` seem to be ok, but if it's `None`, it raises an exception:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg.py", line 487, in __init__
  self._collect_output(p, result, stdin=p.stdin)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg.py", line 561, in _collect_output
  stderr = codecs.getreader(self.encoding)(process.stderr)
File "C:\jython2.5.2\Lib\codecs.py", line 920, in getreader
  return lookup(encoding).streamreader
at org.python.core.codecs.normalizestring(codecs.java:101)
at org.python.core.codecs.lookup(codecs.java:75)
at org.python.modules._codecs.lookup(_codecs.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Looks like there are differences between PyDev and standalone encodings, as well as no (?) encoding  for PyDev/Jython? I'd really like to use the convenient PyDev development environment, but how can I get the `sys.stdin.encoding` to be something sensible when developing a Jython program?

**Update 1**

Maybe the problem is related to one of the following Jython bug reports:

- http://bugs.jython.org/issue1839
- http://bugs.jython.org/issue1807 (see [msg6717](http://bugs.jython.org/msg6717))

But then again, these seem to be independent from PyDev/Eclipse..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a Jython issue:

In PySystemState.java, when setting up the encodings, Jython will skip setting any encoding if it's not a tty console:

```
private void initEncoding() {
    String encoding = registry.getProperty(PYTHON_CONSOLE_ENCODING);
    if (encoding == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (PyFile stdStream : new PyFile[] {(PyFile)this.stdin, (PyFile)this.stdout,
                                          (PyFile)this.stderr}) {
        if (stdStream.isatty()) {
            stdStream.encoding = encoding;
        }
    }
}
```

So, a workaround could be creating a java module to set that (as encoding is a public field of PyFile, but does not have a setter from the Jython side -- or you could use java reflection to set it)...

Maybe you could ask the Jython guys why this is made in the first place (I think the encoding could be set even if it was not a tty device, but I'm not sure which implications could it have and why it's done that way).

**EDIT to summarise the results of the many [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651835/why-is-sys-stdin-encoding-under-pydev-jython-different-from-standalone-jython/9703807#comment12971827_9703807), between the developers of Jython and PyDev as well as the author of the original question (Philip Jenvey, Fabio Zadrozny and [Christian Gelinek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/897968/christian-gelinek), resp.):**

During the progress, a couple of test scripts were discussed and developed:

- A [Python unit test](http://pastebin.com/DNE9v4nX) written by Philip to test different encodings set by minimal custom created *sitecusomize.py* scripts. Fabio [thinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651835/why-is-sys-stdin-encoding-under-pydev-jython-different-from-standalone-jython/9703807#comment12669575_9703807) that the reason for it not actually setting the encoding is because *sys.stdin.encoding* is inherited from the parent process instead configured by the unit test script.
- [A Java test program](http://pastebin.com/382N3hsz) written by Christian which sets up custom I/O streams for creating a Python subprocess, which was found by Fabio to be [more similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651835/why-is-sys-stdin-encoding-under-pydev-jython-different-from-standalone-jython/9703807#comment12770403_9703807) to how PyDev sets up the subprocess.

As this didn't work as expected by Fabio, he [remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651835/why-is-sys-stdin-encoding-under-pydev-jython-different-from-standalone-jython/9703807#comment12971827_9703807) that PyDev also uses the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable.

As was pointed out by Philip, the current (2.5) version of Jython doesn't support the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable, which is used by PyDev (in combination with *sitecusomize.py*) to set the encoding:

> *You can log a bug for it, although PYTHONIOENCODING was only added in CPython 2.6, so Jython probably wouldn't support it until 2.7 (Jython's skipping 2.6).*

Comment: That is indeed interesting, I will check with the Jython team for why it was done that way.

Comment: Looks like it was filed as a [bug (issue #1314) at some point](http://bugs.jython.org/issue1314), unfortunately doesn't tell why...

Comment: Here are parts of the answer from Philip Jenvey who wrote initEncoding(): Looking at the CPython 2.6 source code, the only way I see this behavior changing is if a PYTHONIOENCODING env variable is set: `python2.6 -c "import sys;print '%s %s'%(sys.stdin.isatty(),sys.stdin.encoding)"` gives `True UTF-8`, while `echo|python2.6 -c "import sys;print '%s %s'%(sys.stdin.isatty(),sys.stdin.encoding)"` gives `False None` and `echo|PYTHONIOENCODING=rot13 python2.6 -c "import sys;print '%s %s'%(sys.stdin.isatty(),sys.stdin.encoding)"` gives `False rot13`. @FabioZadrozny, does PyDev use PYTHONIOENCODING?

Comment: Fabio Zadrozny, do you have any comments on this? It doesn't seem like a Jython bug after all. Should I create a bug report in PyDev? I'll do so unless I hear from you in a day.

Comment: PyDev creates a sitecustomize that calls sys.setdefaultencoding with the proper encoding (before that method is deleted from sys) -- it works in Python (so, if Jython differs from Python in that area, it's a Jython issue) -- also, from the Jython implementation, it seems it wouldn't work even if PYTHONIOENCODING is set.

Comment: About the PYTHONIOENCODING, you are correct, that is what Philip Jenvey said that it still is not supported by Jython. I'll ask him if he sees any problems with the sitecustomize.

Comment: In an answer to this, Philip Jenvey writes: AFAIK sys.setdefaultencoding won't affect the encoding of stdin/out/err, because they're already setup by the time you can call that function from Python code. You can try this on Windows, but it doesn't work on POSIX: `echo | python2.6 -S -c "import sys; sys.setdefaultencoding('ascii'); print '%s %s' % (sys.stdin.isatty(), sys.stdin.encoding)"` prints `False None` (-S omits the site module, which deletes sys.defaultencoding).

Comment: He also said: "However I think you can actually set the default encoding before stdin/err/out are setup, but only via the CPython C API (via the PyUnicode_SetDefaultEncoding call). Even if PyDev did this though, I would still expect an stdin.encoding value of None due to the fact that they're not ttys." As far as I understand this, the sys.setdefaultencoding call wouldn't make a difference anyway? So what _does_ PyDev do to set the sys.stdin.encoding? Or is there another way of using a "sitecustomize" (a thing I have never heard before)? Fabio?

Comment: I don't think I quite follow... you're talking about CPython, but in CPython things work already with PyDev (as they should and where PyDev does set the default encoding in the sitecustomize inititialization -- see: http://docs.python.org/library/site.html). The problem is only in Jython when isatty() == false, right?

Comment: Yes, Philip Jenvey talks about CPython because in his opinion, Jython's behaviour is (except for the PYTHONIOENCODING env. var.) the same as CPython's. What I am trying to do here is to find out _why_ there is a difference between PyDev/Jython and PyDev/CPython. Until now, I am not sure if the problem is due to a difference in Jython (as you suggest) or in the way PyDev set up the environments for the interpreters (implied by what Philip Jenvey writes). That's why I am asking you about any differences in how PyDev creates the CPython/Jython execution environments which could affect encoding.

Comment: For me it's pretty clear: Jython has a bug: when sys.setdefaultencoding is called during the site customization, it's properly respected in Python and not in Jython, so, it's mostly an issue of fixing Jython so that if sys.setdefaultencoding is called the sys.stdin.encoding is properly set.

Comment: Fabio, Philip is trying to reproduce the error in Jython but to do that, he needs a test case that works in CPython. He has written a **[test script on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DNE9v4nX)**, but it fails under my CPython 2.7.2 (Win7/cmd.exe)... could you provide a changed version that works with CPython as it should? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work here either and I believe the problem to be in the way that the launching works... it seems that it inherits the sys.stdin.encoding from the parent process: if launching the code: import sys;print '%s|%s' % (sys.getdefaultencoding(), sys.stdin.encoding) from a not atty environment with the sitecustomize in place, it should work as intended, but the problem lies in the environment, so, it'll probably be hard to reproduce this in a test from an existing Python env or using a shell... he could try launching a javaw.exe which in turn launched python.exe with streams properly setup.

Comment: Allright, I created a very **[simple example](http://pastebin.com/iGhnWEYP)** of running the `import sys;print '%s|%s' % (sys.getdefaultencoding(), sys.stdin.encoding)` python code from a java environment. This returned, for both running in Eclipse and in Windows CMD (`java -cp ../bin ConsoleEncTest`), `STDOUT:\nascii|None\nSTDERR:\n`. Which is the same result when running it directly in the CPython _or_ Jython executable from CMD. How does the environment look like when running it in PyDev?

Comment: It's exactly that, but you have to do the sitecustomize doing sys.setdefaultencoding during the launch (i.e.: create a sitecustomize.py with sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') and add the folder containing it to the PYTHONPATH).

Comment: I have updated the **[ConsoleEncTest code](http://pastebin.com/382N3hsz)** to include a (local) sitecustomize, which only writes `starting sitecustomize.` to stdout and calls `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`. ConsoleEncTest's output is: `STDOUT:\nstarting sitecustomize.\nutf-8|None\nSTDERR:` ...is that what you are expecting?

Comment: FabioZadrozny? Any new findings on that issue?

Comment: Ok, took another look at something else that PyDev does that I forgot to mention: it sets the 'PYTHONIOENCODING' environment variable, not only the sys.setdefaultencoding(), so, if you put that env when launching Python on your tests, it should work as inside Eclipse.

Comment: Ah, there we have it! PYTHONIOENCODING, as mentioned above, is not supported (yet) in Jython...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to explicitly encoding on the launch properties.

Run configurations -> Python run -> Xxx -> Common tab -> Encoding.

PyDev inherits some settings from global Eclipse settings. On Linux the encoding is sane UTF-8 everywhere, but some cranky operating systems cause their own issues..

Also you can probably detect encoding in your .py main module and have PyDev specific hack to fix problems related to your configuration.

Comment: Yes, my "cranky" operating system is Windows XP :) ...anyway, in the Common tab you mentioned, the initial Encoding setting was `Default - inherited (Cp1252)`, which correlates to what I see when running PyDev/Python. I also tried changing it to `Other: ISO-8859-1` or `Other: UTF-8`, but for PyDev/Jython at least, it didn't make any difference - `sys.stdin.encoding` is still `None` for all three settings.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe then force encoding inside Jython somehow? (as using .py code)

Comment: You mean as in Blauohr's answer? That didn't work either... or do you have another idea?